# Not getting string value from user defaults after it being set in App Delegate

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Here is the code from my app delegate specifically the function that is handling the url copied directly from the firebase tutorial

```
func handlePasswordlessSignIn(withURL url: URL) -> Bool {
    let link = url.absoluteString
    // [START is_signin_link]
    if Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link) {
        // [END is_signin_link]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(link, forKey: "Link")
        print("shit worked")
        return true
    }
    print("shit aint work")
    return false
}
```

In the view controller function that is supposed to use the link to sign user in from the email verification, it says that link is nil, here is the code below

```
func signInUserAfterEmailLinkClick(){
if let link = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Link") as? String {
        self.link = link}
    // Sign user in with the link and email
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: EmailField.text!, link: self.link) { (user, error) in
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if let error = error {
            self.handleSignUpError(error: error)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm dying to look lookat your code lol. Slect all rows and press `Ctrl + I` to reindent your code.
For your problem, `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:link:)` is an asynchronous method. It will get results after your view controller's `viewDidAppear` get called.
So try to load it in launch screen controller and wait before showing your viewcontroller

Comment: The problem is that your "after" is actually "before".